# neo4j path traverser description

Tags: java, neo4j

1. With the definition of the RelationshipTypes as

   private enum Rels implements RelationshipType {
       LIKES, KNOWS } The graph can be traversed with for example the following traverser, starting at the “Joe” node:

   for ( Path position : Traversal.description()
           .depthFirst()
           .relationships( Rels.KNOWS )
           .relationships( Rels.LIKES, Direction.INCOMING )
           .evaluator( Evaluators.toDepth( 5 ) )
           .traverse( node ) ) {
       output += position + "\n"; } The traversal will output:

   (7) (7)<--[LIKES,1]--(4) (7)<--[LIKES,1]--(4)--[KNOWS,6]-->(1)
   (7)<--[LIKES,1]--(4)--[KNOWS,6]-->(1)--[KNOWS,4]-->(6)
   (7)<--[LIKES,1]--(4)--[KNOWS,6]-->(1)--[KNOWS,4]-->(6)--[KNOWS,3]-->(5)
   (7)<--[LIKES,1]--(4)--[KNOWS,6]-->(1)--[KNOWS,4]-->(6)--[KNOWS,3]-->(5)--[KNOWS,2]-->(2) (7)<--[LIKES,1]--(4)--[KNOWS,6]-->(1)<--[KNOWS,5]--(3)

   if we take (7)<--[LIKES,1]--(4) what does number 1 represent ?

   thanks in advance for more info
   http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorial-traversal-java-api.html

Comment: pls paste the output of the folowing cypher query: `start n=node({Joe}) match p=n-[*1..5]-n2 return p;`

Comment: ==> | [Node[7]{name:"Joe"},:KNOWS[3] {},Node[2]{name:"Sara"}]                                                                                                                                          |
==> | [Node[7]{name:"Joe"},:KNOWS[3] {},Node[2]{name:"Sara"},:KNOWS[2] {},Node[5]{name:"Peter"}]                                                                                                       |
==> | [Node[7]{name:"Joe"},:KNOWS[3] {},Node[2]{name:"Sara"},:KNOWS[2] {},Node[5]{name:"Peter"},:KNOWS[1] {},Node[6]{name:"Dirk"}]

Comment: and there are mooooooore result

Comment: ok this didn't match the specific set. could you please paste output of this? `start n=node(7) match p=n-[r:LIKES]-n2 return p;`. my point is to see whether it could really be the Id or not.

Comment: p                                                       |
==> +---------------------------------------------------------+
==> | [Node[7]{name:"Joe"},:LIKES[6] {},Node[4]{name:"Lisa"}] |
==> +---------------------------------------------------------+
==> 1 row

Answer (score 3):

That's probably the id of the edge

Comment: it is the relationship-id. Both nodes and relationships have id's.